# PayPal Payments Standard - change shipping and handling to just shipping

Tags: php, paypal

I am using PayPal Payments Standard with my own button code as follows.  This works exactly as I would like except for one thing.  In the PayPal shopping cart and on the invoicing, the display shows "Shipping and Handling".  In California, I have to pay taxes on Handling fees.  Can I make the display show "Shipping" only without the "Handling?

I tried to pass both a "handling" and a "handling-cart" input attribute with both empty and zero as values but that had no impact.

```
<form target="paypal" action="<?=PAYPAL_URL?>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?=PAYPAL_BUSINESS?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.50">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="<?=$url?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="5.00" />
  <input type="hidden" name="shipping2" value="5.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="stain">
  <input type="image" src="images/add_to_cart.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="Add to Cart">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```